# How do I check if a module $M=\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ is finitely presented?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and take $M=\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}\in Mod_R$. I want to check if it is finitely presented.

I have the following definition:

> If $M$ is an $R$ module generated by $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ then we have a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $$\bigoplus_{i\in I} R \rightarrow M;~~~~e_i\mapsto x_i~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ Let $K=\ker\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I} R \rightarrow M\right)$ then take $(x_j)_{j\in J\subset I}$ the generating family of the kernel and we also have a surjective homomorphism $$\bigoplus_{j\in J} R\rightarrow K~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$ All in all we get to this right exact sequence $$\bigoplus_{j\in J} R\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I} R \rightarrow M\rightarrow 0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$We say that $M$ is finitely presented if $I,J$ are finite and we have an above presentation.

Now W wanted to check if my module $M$ is finitely generated or not. I thought that I first need to find such $(x_i)$ and then such a $R$-module homomorphism. I mean since the $x_i$ need to generate $M$ and we know that $M=\{\bar 0,\bar 1,...,\bar 5\}$ the only generator is $\bar 1$ because I can get to the others by adding it with itself. Is this correct? So my map $(1)$ would be $R\rightarrow M; ~~1\rightarrow \bar 1$ but then the kernel of this map would be $6\Bbb{Z}$ right? So I indeed have such a presentation:

$$\Bbb{Z}\stackrel{\cdot 6}{\rightarrow} \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$  where $\cdot 6$ denotes the multiplication by $6$ right?

Did I do this correct or am I completely wrong?

Now I would like to check if it is also projective or not because I want to have an example/counterexample of the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M\in Mod_R$ an finitely presented then the following are equivalent:
>
> - $M$ is locally free
> - $M$ is projective
> - $M$ is flat

Thanks for your help

Comment: The kernel is not zero. Where does 6 go?

Comment: @Pedro sorry sure $6\Bbb{Z}$ is the kernel right?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Pedro but this would mean that we have the following "presentation" $\Bbb{Z}\stackrel{\cdot 6}{\rightarrow} \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ right? ($\cdot 6$ denotes the multiplication by $6$)

Comment: @Pedro as I added above I would also like to check if $M$ is projective or not so that I can get an example of the theorem I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, over a PID every finitely generated module is finitely presented, due to the property unique to PID’s: that is, over a PID, every submodule of a free module is free.

In your case, the natural surjection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ yields a following free presentation:
$$6 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z} \to 0,$$
where $6 \mathbb{Z}$ is a kernel of a surjection and $6 \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

UPD: to see that the module is not flat, consider the above presentation, which is also exact on the left, and tensor it with the module in question. Now it remains to see that what you get is a sequence not exact on the left.

UPD2: you have an injective map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, n \mapsto 6n$, which becomes zero map after tensoring with the module in question - that is how you can see it is not flat; an example of a module satisfying the conditions of the theorem is, for example, any free module

Comment: Thank you I think I have got to the same presentation. Now as I added above I want to check if it's projective. I know that this means that per definition I need t check that $Hom(M,-)$ is exact or that all short exact sequences $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B \rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ splits i.e. $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow  A\oplus M\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ right?

Comment: @Haveaniceday it cannot be projective as it is not flat

Comment: Ah okey so I first need to show that it is not flat. Can one do this easily by showing $M\otimes-$ is left exact?

Comment: Could I take the sequence $0\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ and then remark that if I apply $ M\otimes -$ I get $ M\rightarrow M\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ which is not left exact

Comment: yes that is what you should do. pay attention to the maps though, as that is where the trick is hidden

Comment: sorry I don't get this one with the trick what do you mean?

Comment: So I mean the "first" exact sequence is like the presentation above only with a zero on the left

Comment: Could you also maybe give me an example which satisfies the above theorem I stated? So finitely presented and either flat, projective or locally free?

Comment: you either have all of them, or none of them: that is the statement of your theorem, so you’re asking and impossible thing

Comment: Why is this impossible so is this statement only used when I want to show that none of them is satisfied?

Comment: Or do you say that the statement is wrong because this means our prof have a wrong statement

Comment: @Haveaniceday i updated my answer; you’re asking many questions at once; initially your question was only about the module being finitely presented - I think you should consider asking another question instead of editing this one

Comment: i see thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a (left) **Noetherian** ring, *every finitely generated (left) $R$-module is finitely presented*.

Why? Well, if you take a finitely generated (left) $R$-module $M$, then there is a positive integer $n$ and an epimorphism $\varphi \colon R^n \to M$.

As $R$ is left Noetherian, $R^n$ is a Noetherian (left) $R$-module; hence $\ker \varphi$ is finitely generated as well, so there is a positive integer $m$ and an epimorphism $R^m \to \ker \varphi$.

Composing the latter with the inclusion $\ker \varphi \to R^n$ we obtain a homomorphism $R^m \to R^n$, which fits into an exact sequence $$R^m \longrightarrow R^n \stackrel \varphi \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0.$$